# Zend AMF throwing InvocationTargetException

Tags: php, zend-framework, flex4, amf

I am trying to make a service call to a php function from flex, through Zend AMF. Most of the functions get called fine, but for one particular function, it throws the following exception:

> InvocationTargetException:There was an
>   error while invoking the operation.
>   Check your operation inputs or server
>   code and try invoking the operation
>   again.
>
> Reason:  Fatal error: Call to a member
>   function getInvokeArguments() on a
>   non-object in
>   D:\wamp\www\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Amf\Server.php
>   on line 328

I am not able to debug through this - has anyone faced any issue like this before, or have any ideas how this can be debugged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally realized that this was a problem in the flex project setup - don't know exactly what it was, but once we deleted and created the project again, things started working fine!

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance through ZFW's source, this appears to be a bug on their framework.

```
// There is no check if $this->_table[$qualifiedName] is an object, implements an interface, extends a class, only if it's set (the key exists).
$info = $this->_table[$qualifiedName];
$argv = $info->getInvokeArguments(); // Here's when you get the error.
```

Source: http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=/trunk/library/Zend/Amf/Server.php

I looked in their bug tracker and haven't found anything related to this, perhaps you should open a new issue?

Additionally, you can debug the problem by grabbing the message that Flex is sending to the PHP client and making a test case out of it.

Comment: Thanks I thought so but couldn't think of a workaround - any chance I can get a quickfix/quick workaround for this? Clients waiting :(

Comment: I don't even mind paid support options right now, but flex supports not available on weekend!